# Как избежать отличий в работе тестового и боевого серверов?

Tags: tomcat

Есть тестовый сервер, на котором отрабатываются все доработки. После этого всё переносится на продакшн. И часто бывает так, что боевой сервер работает не так как тестовый и появляются всякие баги. Есть ли какое-нибудь решение данной проблемы, чтобы пользователь не сталкивался с багами?

Comment: Полностью автоматизировать настройку тестового и боевого серверов и настраивать их полностью одинаково одними и теми же скриптами. И никогда не лезть на сервер что-то редактировать вручную - всё делать только через автоматические скрипты.

Comment: А если БД для тестового и продуктового серверов не одинаковые?  Полной идентичности не получится тогда. И всё равно будут вылизать ошибки у конечного пользователя.

Comment: Если ошибки способна вызывать всего лишь немного отличающиеся данные в БД, то у вас чудовищно кривой и глючный проект, который нужно срочно переписать с нуля :)

Comment: Тем не менее вещи, которые не зависят от пользовательских данных (списки городов, валют, часовых поясов, категории чего-нибудь и т.п.), а также настройка таблиц, индексов и внешних ключей тоже замечательно автоматизируются и должны быть одинаковыми на тесте и на проде. Любая «взрослая» ORM поддерживает механизмы миграций и фикстур в том или ином виде и может обеспечить одинаковость теста и прода в таких местах БД.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понимаю ваш вопрос. Для таких целей используются средства разработки, такие как vagrant, docker и т.п. С их помощью можно создать среду разработки, воссоздающую такую же среду как не продакшен сервере. Что помогает избежать ошибок связанных с различием между средой в которой разрабатывалось ПО и в которой оно будет выполняться.

Answer (score 0):

Этта проблема всегда была и будет - один из вариантов решения - настраивать тестовый сервер/сервера в максимально полной одинаковости/идентичности с клиентским/рабочим.

На самом деле, утрясываются базовые моменты - версии языка и базы, а также серверной реализации - nginx или apach, например - потому как, решения в htaccess на клиенте/ чистом nginx работать не будут, без соответствующего переноса на nginx.
Оставляется рабочее время на установку и апробирование клиентом решения - или на самостоятельную установку у клиента, если таковое предусмотрено соглашением.

Добавлю - часто приходится и непредусмотренное допиливать на машине клиента, за те же деньги - ибо клиент заказывал рабочее решение для своей машины, а не вообще где-то и как-то - что, конечно, занимает достаточно дополнительного времени и нервов.